# Dragable infinite loop carousel, performance issues on dragging large number (25+) of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two instances of this carousel to test with, one with 7 slides and the other with 25. They run the exact same code. The 7 slide instance drags smoothly forever as intended, but the 25 slide instance is choppy when dragging.

Something in the dragMove event is slowing down execution when the slide count is higher, and I'd like to find a way to improve it so that the slide count has no effect on performance.

I've already tried a few optimizations, like replacing:

```
$slider.children().last()
```

with

```
$Slider[0].lastChild
```

To bypass instantiating of all those unnecessary Jquery objects just to get the last one, but dragging is still choppy.

Here's the dragMove event:

```
function dragMove(event){
  var ev = event.originalEvent || event || window.event;      
  var MousePosition = GetEventCoordinates(ev);      
  var MouseMoveDistance = (MousePosition.x-locals.StartingMousePosition.x);
  var DistanceDifference = (locals.LastMouseMoveDistance-MouseMoveDistance);
  var MoveDirection = (DistanceDifference === 0 || isNaN(DistanceDifference)) ? locals.LastMoveDirection : (DistanceDifference>0) ? '<' : '>' ; // negative to the left
  var StepsMoved = Math.floor(MouseMoveDistance/base.protected.ItemWidth);
  var StepsDifference = (locals.LastStepsMoved-StepsMoved);

  if(StepsDifference !== 0 || locals.LastMoveDirection !== MoveDirection){
     // Steps has changed, recalculate!
     var oEdgeCounts = base.GetEdgeCounts();

     if(oEdgeCounts.left<1 && MoveDirection==='>'){
        // There are non to the left, but we need some!
        if(StepsDifference===0){StepsDifference=1;}
        for(var i=0; i<Math.abs(StepsDifference); i++){               
           $Last = $(base.protected.$Slider[0].lastChild);
           base.protected.$Slider.prepend($Last);
        }
        locals.PopAdjustment = (locals.PopAdjustment+(Math.abs(StepsDifference)*base.protected.ItemWidth));
     }

     if(oEdgeCounts.right<1 && MoveDirection==='<'){
        //There are none to the right, but we need some!
        if(StepsDifference===0)StepsDifference=1;
        for(var i=0; i<Math.abs(StepsDifference); i++){               
           $First = $(base.protected.$Slider[0].firstChild);
           base.protected.$Slider.append($First);
        }
        locals.PopAdjustment = (locals.PopAdjustment-(Math.abs(StepsDifference)*base.protected.ItemWidth));
     }
  }      

  locals.NewSliderLeft = GetEventCoordinates(ev).x - locals.DragStartTouchOffsetX-locals.PopAdjustment;      

  // Save values so we can compare on next event      
  locals.LastSampleMousePosition = MousePosition;
  locals.LastMouseMoveDistance = MouseMoveDistance;
  locals.LastMoveDirection = MoveDirection;
  locals.LastStepsMoved = StepsMoved;

  base.protected.$Slider.css('left',locals.NewSliderLeft);
}
```

Here is the get Edge count function. It uses simple math to determin the number of slides off the left and off the right sides. I don't think it's speed is impacted by slide count.

```
GetEdgeCounts = function(){       
   var base = this;       
   var SliderLeft = parseInt(base.protected.$Slider.css('left'),10);
   var OffLeftCount = Math.abs(SliderLeft)/base.protected.ItemWidth;
   var OffLeftFloor = Math.floor(OffLeftCount);
   var OffRightCount = base.protected.TotalItems-base.protected.ItemsPerPage-OffLeftCount;
   var OffRightFloor = Math.floor(OffRightCount);

   OffRightFloor = (OffRightFloor >=0) ? OffRightFloor : 0;
   OffLeftFloor = (OffLeftFloor >=0) ? OffLeftFloor : 0;
   return{
      left:OffLeftFloor,
      right:OffRightFloor,
      center:base.protected.ItemsPerPage
   };
}
```

I'm looking for any ideas on how to make dragging with larger slide counts less choppy.

Comment: can you add an operational fiddle for this at http://jsfiddle.net/ or give a Github repo? I want to see the DOM as well

Comment: Chrome's timeline and profiler will help you figure out what is taking so much time. Activate the debugger, go to timeline, click the red circle to record, make your choppy drag happen, and stop the record by clicking the red circle again. Zoom into the timeline around the part where you did the drag and look for the widest bar(s). Mouse over it and it will tell you what it was doing. Let us know what you find is the time consumer, if you try this.

Answer (score 3):

From a once over, some performance tips:

- At least on some versions of Chrome, `parseInt(string,10);` is [slower](http://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/24) than a number of alternatives, my preference is `+string`
- It is [faster](http://jsperf.com/math-abs-vs-string-casting/2) to call `Math.abs(string)` than `Math.abs(parseInt(string,10))`
- Each object property lookup has a cost, so consider `var base = this.protected;` since all your object accesses are on `base.protected'
- Be wary of ternary operators, a regular `if` tends to be [faster](http://jsperf.com/math-min-max-vs-ternary-vs-if)
- Your code has actually a number of little inefficiencies

  - You will capture `var MousePosition = GetEventCoordinates(ev);` but then later you still call `locals.NewSliderLeft = GetEventCoordinates(ev).x - locals.DragStartTouchOffsetX-locals.PopAdjustment;`
  - You store `locals.NewSliderLeft` but you use it only once in the assignment here: `base.protected.$Slider.css('left',locals.NewSliderLeft);`, I would skip storing this value in `locals` altogether.
- From a style perspective, I would suggest that you use more spaces and fewer parentheses so `var MouseMoveDistance = (MousePosition.x-locals.StartingMousePosition.x);` becomes 
  `var MouseMoveDistance = MousePosition.x - locals.StartingMousePosition.x;`
- Also prefixing in general is discouraged (`oEdgeCounts`)
- From a [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) perspective, the block of `if(oEdgeCounts.left<1 && MoveDirection==='>'){` and `if(oEdgeCounts.right<1 && MoveDirection==='<'){` is pretty much copy pasted, you should refactor that

All in all, your code is quite readable and maintainable and I dont see immediately where the culprit is. I fully endorse the opion of Doug Gale to use the Chrome developer tools to find the culprit.

Comment: On FF 30, `Bitwise >> (right shift)` and `Multiply (force cast)` were the fastest with the `plus operator` running slower than parseInt().

Comment: Hah, go figure..